# Wait IHttpContextAccessor to initialize before the creation of dbcontext used as services

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are using database per tenant logic for our application.
We currently need to build the connection string dynamically depending on the currently logged user.

We would really like to use the tenant database context as a service (DI). However, the dbcontext initialization is done in the configure services method and the IHttpContextAccessor is null at this stage.

Is there a way to call services.addDbContext but notify him to wait until IHttpContextAccessor is instanced? or I really need to instance it each time?

Thanks!

Here some of my code :

```
    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
services.AddDbContext<ESDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(new DataConnectionAPI(sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(),sp.GetService<ESUsersContext>()).DataConnectionString(), ma => ma.MigrationsAssembly("ESData")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest to not to use AddDbContext, but register services by yourself.
Something like that:

```
        services
            .AddScoped<ESDataContext>()
            .AddScoped(sp =>
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ESDataContext>()
                    .UseSqlServer(
                        new DataConnectionAPI(
                            sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), 
                            sp.GetService<ESUsersContext>()
                            ).DataConnectionString())
                    .Options)
```

After you can build service provider.

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to register a factory that modifies the connection string at runtime and returns the contexts instance. `IHttpContextAccessor` is only available during a http-request same goes for all informations that are necessary to access the users information because the authorize filter must be executed first.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters

**Edit:**

You wouldn't register the db-context in your configureservice method.

You would create a constructor within your DbContext that takes [DbContextOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions) (base-constructor). You would create a DbContextFactory that injects HttpContextAccesor and whatever necessary and then inject this factory at runtime to createa DbContext manually and return the value.

Then register the factory

```
services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory();
```

**Attention:** Don't implement a [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-2.0) for this purpose, this should be used for creating migrations only.

Comment: My dbcontext would still be created at this stage. I'm not sure I could reinstance it from the factory.

Comment: Updated the answer.